# oracle apex - configuring flash charts as Line & Area chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, oracle-apex

Though I'm grateful for the built-in interactive graphs in APEX I'm unsure it allows what I need.

Let's say I have a graph with 2 metrics, 
the built-in charting flash shows the current value for each one when I hover over one of them.

Is there a way to show both values in a statically positioned box as I hover through the x-axis independent of the y-axis?

(Either check http://www.amcharts.com/line/
or the upper left corner of a google finance graph like http://www.google.com/finance?q=AAPL to have an idea)

Do I have to integrate it with an external solution like open-flash-chart, amcharts or Google Chart Tools?

Comment: I'm probably going to follow George Triantafyllidis instructions to build something like (just not for stocks)
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=354:3:4334166310589134:::::